# Clearing files from Cloudflare API via Powershell randomly stops working

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-storage

This is my first time making a script for an API call, so if I am making stupid or silly mistakes, please be nice about it :)

Brief overview:

- I am monitoring for file system changes. When my monitor detects a file being changed in a certain directory (recursively), the script will fire off an API call to Cloudflare and clear the file from Cloudflare's caching servers.
- The script is compiled into an EXE using [PS2EXE](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PS2EXE-GUI-Convert-e7cb69d5). I then have the script installed as a service, using [NSSM](https://nssm.cc/).
- I have to make some unique adjustments and take the local filename, and convert it to the API specifications in [Cloudflare's API Documentation](https://encrypted.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi6xMr8lJfZAhWkzlkKHcvfDfEQFggoMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.cloudflare.com%2F&usg=AOvVaw2z9OaKOq3sdu10G00JxtVK)
- This system is running on [Azure and uses Azure File Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-windows). This is why I need to test for the path when the service is started because Azure File Storage mapping needs specific settings (Lines 4-13). These machines are not joined to any domain. If anyone has a better method, I'm all ears.

Issue:

The script just... stops working after some time? Most of the time, my logs do not catch the error. It's almost like the file system watcher is just not "watching" anymore. The log merely stops and doesn't process any more calls. If I run into an error, I want the script to ideally stop immediately by restarting the service. If I cannot restart the service, I want the script to immediately tell me by capturing the error message and sending me an email and then stop running entirely.

If I do run into an error, the script fails to restart the service. I imagine this is because my logic is incorrect regarding restarting the service.

My question is:

- Can I restart the service within the script? (Lines 48-55)
- What can I do to make this stop becoming so inconsistent? Ideally I don't want to have to restart the job or the machine. (I've noticed if I restart the job, it doesn't necessarily kill the watcher jobs.)

Edit Note: I am temporarily using my smtp credentials in-script until I can figure out why its so inconsistent and then adjust this so the smtp credentials are properly secured with a keyfile and the like.

Here's the script:

```
Start-Transcript C:\Utilities\Transcript\filetranscript-errorchecking.txt -Append

# Check to see if file is mapped and correct the action if not.
switch (Test-Path S:\Root)
{
    $false {
        & cmdkey /add:azurefilestore.file.core.windows.net /user:AZURE\azurefileuser /pass:**passkey**
        & net use S: \\azurefilestore.file.core.windows.net\web /u:AZURE\azurefileuser **passkey**
    }
    $true {
        Write-Output "File is already mapped. Doing nothing."
    }
}

### SET FOLDER TO WATCH + FILES TO WATCH + SUBFOLDERS YES/NO
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = "S:\Root"
$watcher.Filter = "*.*"
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true  

#####CLOUDFLARE HEADERS#####
$auth_email = 'cloudflareuser@organization.com'
$zone_key = 'cloudflare-key'
$auth_token = 'cloudflare-auth-token'
$headers = @{'X-Auth-Key'=$auth_token;'X-Auth-Email'=$auth_email;'Content-Type'='application/json'}


$emailun = "smtprelayemail@organization.com"
$emailpw = "myemailsmtp" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($emailun,$emailpw)
$date = Get-Date

### DEFINE ACTIONS AFTER AN EVENT IS DETECTED
    $action = { 
                $body = $event.SourceEventArgs.Fullpath -replace 'S\:\\Root\\','https://websiteurl.url.com/' -replace ' ','%20' -replace '\\','/'
                # Re-enable below line for testing by removing comment. See next comment note #39.
                # [string]$placedstring = 'break{"files":["' + $body + '"]}'
                # IMPORTANT: Comment the below line when testing.
                [string]$placedstring = '{"files":["' + $body + '"]}'
                Write-Host "$placedstring"
                    Try
                    {
                        # We want the script to STOP and send us an e-mail if an issue is detected.
                        Invoke-RestMethod -uri "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/$zone_key/purge_cache" -Method DELETE -Headers $headers -body $placedstring -ErrorAction Stop -Verbose
                        # Write-Output $placedstring "is being removed."
                    }
                    Catch
                    {
                        $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
                        Send-MailMessage –From smtprelayemail@organization.com –To myemail@organization.com –Subject "Cloudflare API failure on Azure!" –Body "There was an issue with the Cloudflare API calls. The error was: $ErrorMessage. The Cloudflare API is now being restarted..." -SmtpServer smtp.server.com -Credential $cred -UseSsl -Port 587 -Verbose

                            try {
                                Restart-Service -Name "CloudflareAPI-Error" -Force -ErrorAction Stop
                            }

                            catch {
                                $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
                                Send-MailMessage –From smtprelayemail@organization.com –To myemail@organization.com –Subject "Unable to restart service for Cloudflare" –Body "The error was: $ErrorMessage." -SmtpServer smtp.server.com -Credential $cred -UseSsl -Port 587 -Verbose
                            }
                    }
              }  

### DECIDE WHICH EVENTS SHOULD BE WATCHED 
Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Changed" -Action $action
Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Deleted" -Action $action
Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Renamed" -Action $action
while ($true) {sleep 5}
```

Sample log output:

```
{"files":["https://websiteurl.url.com/main.css"]}
VERBOSE: DELETE https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/apit-zone-key/purge_cache with -1-byte payload
VERBOSE: received -1-byte response of content type application/json
{"files":["https://websiteurl.url.com/main.css"]}
```

Comment: Were you able to found a solution for this or do you still need help for it ?

Comment: Adam - thanks for the reply. No, we do not need help anymore. Unfortunately, we did not resolve the situation. We felt there may be some internal issue we weren't seeing with the FileSystemWatcher class. If you have any insight, it'll definitely help for future projects.